# How can we count the number of combinations without casework in this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

This is an interesting problem that I remembered today:

If a billboard can be painted either red, orange, or yellow, and it is never painted red for 3 days in a row, then how many paint-sequences could possibly show up in the duration of one week?

My first thought was to just list all the possibilities, as I believed there wouldn't be many, but I felt that this was probably not the solution that was intended to solve this problem.

Then, I thought that perhaps I could use casework with complementary counting (so I would try counting possibilities where there *are* 3 days in a row where the board is painted red, and I would do casework over which of the 7 days in the week is the first day within the 3 days in a row). However, I found a problem with this method, which is that when doing two different cases, say, some of the possibilities may overlap, and I don't know how to account for this overcounting.

So, can someone confirm if my general thinking here is correct at all? Or is there another solution besides casework that can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd work recursively.  Every good sequence must begin with one of $X, RX, RRX$ where $X$ is not red.

Comment: @lulu See the Addendum to my answer.  I guess that I owe you a *royalty*.

Comment: @user2661923  That is a very thorough answer! (+1)   Perhaps it is simpler to just note that every good word of length $n$ is either a good word of length $n-1$ preceded by an $X$, or a good word of length $n-2$ preceded by $RX$, or $n-3$ preceded by $R^2 X$, hence $a_n=2(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3})$.  Which, sadly, lacks a pleasant closed form, but which is, of course, easily computable for modest $n$,

Comment: @lulu I thought of that.  Your way probably is simpler.  Unfortunately, I had trouble working my head around a *right-to-left* analysis.  Therefore, I went with a left-to-right analysis, which is not that bad, as recursions go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added an Addendum which highjacks the idea in lulu's comment.

---

As others have discussed, the problem reduces to enumerating how many ways there are of having at least one occurrence of 3 consecutive *red* days in the week.

David's answer discusses the **direct** approach; the alternative approach is [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

It is not uncommon in problems like this, that involve a small number (i.e. only $7$ days in the week), for the direct approach to be easier than Inclusion-Exclusion.  However, the alternative consideration is that Inclusion-Exclusion **generalizes well**.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion:

Let a sequence like r-x-r-r-r-x-x represent that days 1, 3, 4, and 5, were red, and the other days were unknown.

Let : 
$A_1$ represent r-r-r-x-x-x-x. 
$A_2$ represent x-r-r-r-x-x-x. 
$A_3$ represent x-x-r-r-r-x-x. 
$A_4$ represent x-x-x-r-r-r-x. 
$A_5$ represent x-x-x-x-r-r-r.

I will let $T_k ~k: ~k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ represent the number of ways that there are **at least** $k$ occurrences of 3 consecutive red days, in the 7 day week.  Then, the final computation will be:

$$T_1 - T_2 + T_3 - T_4 + T_5$$.

---

The number of ways of sequence $A_1$ occurring is $3^4$.  Since the same enumeration holds for $A_2, A_3, A_4,$ and $A_5$:

$T_1 = 5 \times 3^4 = 405.$

So, $T_1$ represents the enumeration where there is at least one sequence of 3 consecutive red days.

---

Then, in order to enumerate $T_2$, you have to enumerate $A_r \cap A_s ~: ~1 \leq r < s \leq 5.$

$A_1 \cap A_2 ~: ~ 3^3.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_3 ~: ~ 3^2.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^1.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^1.$

$A_2 \cap A_3 ~: ~ 3^3.$ 
$A_2 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^2.$ 
$A_2 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^1.$

$A_3 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^3.$ 
$A_3 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^2.$

$A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^3.$

Therefore, 
$T_2 = (4 \times 3^3) + (3 \times 3^2) + (3 \times 3^1) = 144.$

---

Now, to compute $T_3$, you have to enumerate $A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t ~: ~1 \leq r < s < t \leq 5.$

$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 ~: ~ 3^2.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^1.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$

$A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^1.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$

$A_1 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$

$A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^2.$ 
$A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^1.$

$A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^1.$

$A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^2.$

Therefore, 
$T_3 = (3 \times 3^2) + (4 \times 3^1) + (3 \times 3^0) = 42.$

---

Now, to compute $T_4$, you have to enumerate $A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t \cap A_u ~: ~1 \leq r < s < t < u \leq 5.$

$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 ~: ~ 3^1.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$ 
$A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$ 
$A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^1.$

Therefore, 
$T_4 = (2 \times 3^1) + (3 \times 3^0) = 9.$

---

Now, to compute $T_5$, you have to enumerate $A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t \cap A_u \cap A_v ~: ~1 \leq r < s < t < u < v \leq 5.$

$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 ~: ~ 3^0.$

Therefore, 
$T_5 = 1.$

---

Final answer:

$$T_1 - T_2 + T_3 - T_4 + T_5 = 405 - 144 + 42 - 9 + 1 = 295.$$

Therefore, there are $295$ distinct paint sequences that violate the constraint of not having 3 consecutive red days.

Therefore, there are $3^7 - (295) = 2187 - 295 = 1892$ 
paint sequences that do not violate the constraint.

**Confession** : I did Java-sanity-check.

---

**Addendum**
Hijacking the idea in lulu's comment.

Let $f(k,n) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k \in \{0,1,2\}~$ denote the number of $n$ character sequences that end with $k$ "R"-s.  Here, it is assumed that no sequence can have 3 consecutive "R"-s, and that each character is "R", "O", or "Y".

Let "p" denote any character other than "R". 
Let "q" denote any of the three characters.

Then, 
$f(0,3)$, which is represented by qqp, $~= 3^2 \times 2 = 18.$ 
$f(1,3)$, which is represented by qpR, $~= 3  \times 2 = 6.$ 
$f(2,3)$, which is represented by pRR, $~= 2.$

The easiest way to develop the recursion formulas is to manually compute $f(0,4), f(1,4),$ and $f(2,4)$.  Then, check whether the transition from $(n=3)$ to $(n=4)$ will hold for $n \to (n+1).$

To compute $f(0,4)$, note that any of the sequences represented by $f(0,3), f(1,3),$ or $f(2,3)$ can be continued by either an "O" or a "Y".

Therefore, 
$f(0,4) = 2 \times [f(0,3) + f(1,3) + f(2,3)].$

To compute $f(1,4)$, you must start with a sequence represented by $f(0,3)$ and then add an "R" to the end of it.

Therefore, 
$f(1,4) = f(0,3)$.

Similarly, to compute $f(2,4)$, you must start with a sequence represented by $f(1,3)$ and then add an "R" to the end of it.

Therefore, 
$f(2,4) = f(1,3)$.

---

In considering the transition from $n \to (n+1)$, the analysis of the transition from $(3) \to (4)$ holds.

Therefore 
$f(0,n+1) = 2 \times [f(0,n) + f(1,n) + f(2,n)].$ 
$f(1,n+1) = f(0,n)$. 
$f(2,n+1) = f(1,n)$.

This leads to the following table:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                                          
  n & f(0,n) & f(1,n) & f(2,n) \\
  \hline  
  3 & 18 & 6 & 2 \\
  \hline  
  4 & 52 & 18 & 6 \\
  \hline 
  5 & 152 & 52 & 18 \\
  \hline  
  6 & 444 & 152 & 52 \\
  \hline  
  7 & 1296 & 444 & 152 \\
  \hline   
\end{array}

$1296 + 444 + 152 = 1892.$

Comment: Does this account for interchanges between orange and yellow ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes it does.  That is, if you examine $A_1$, which I computed to represent $3^4$ sequences, the computation was based on $r-r-r-x-x-x-x$ having $4$ unconstrained days.  Each unconstrained day had 3 choices: red,yellow, orange.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach, although one that won't generalize well.

How many ways are there to paint the billboard so that it's never red?  $2^7=128.$

How many ways are there to paint the billboard so that it's red on $1$ day? $7 \cdot 2^6=7 \cdot 64= 448$.

How many ways are there to paint the billboard so that it's red on $2$ days?  $\binom 72 \cdot 2^5= 672$.

How many ways are there to paint the billboard so that it's red on $3$ days?  There are $\binom 73 -5 = 30$ acceptable ways to choose the red days, so there are $30 \cdot 2^4 = 480$.

How many ways are there to paint the billboard so that it's red on $4$ days?  There are $19$ possible positions for the $3$ non-red days, so there are $19 \cdot 2^3=152$.

How many ways are there to paint the billboard so that it's red on $5$ days?  There are $3$ possible positions for the $2$ non-red days, so there are $3 \cdot 2^2=12$.

There is no way to paint the billboard so that it's red on $6$ or more days, so our total is $1892$.

Comment: +1 : you beat me to it.  I was going to add an Addendum, showing the direct approach, which is what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the most elegant way to do it, but I'd just count the total number of paintings without the rule against three reds, then I'd try to separate out all of the scenarios that have three reds and subtract them off. These latter are, I believe, ones with a sequence of 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7 reds in a row, starting on any possible day, plus the odd scenario out: two separate sequences of three reds each separated by one non-red day in the middle.